# Empty var/lib/jenkins directory installing Jenkins on CentOS 5.8

Tags: jenkins, centos

---

I have a problem with Jenkins installation. I've installed Jenkins many times on different machines and different platforms (Win XP, Win 7, Ubuntu 11.04, Ubuntu 12.04, CentOS 6) always with no problem until now.

Now I have to install Jenkins on a CentOS 5.8 machine, I follow the steps from http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/

everything seems OK, but when I navigate to

```
/var/lib/jenkins
```

folder is empty (I run a `ls -l` command). It supose to have some default files and folders like

- config.xml (file)
- fingerprints (folder)
- jobs (folder)
- plugins (folder)
- workspace (folder)

I've tried installing different jenkins versions, but the result is the same an empty **jenkins** folder

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try actually going to the instance through the web browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the answer.

I was trying to install latest version of jenkins, I have java 5, but latest jenkins version doesn't work with java 5.

I tried, then, install an older jenkins version, and everythig works perfect

sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

You said you followed [**this**](http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/).

That page does not include:
`sudo service jenkins start/stop/restart`
but it does include a link to the [**wiki**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+RedHat+distributions) that explains that.

Could it be that you just didn't start it, if all you did was follow the instructions of the first link without reading the second?

Comment: I run "sudo service jenkins start" and got an "OK" answer, but when I try to connect via web browser "my.jenkins.host:8080" I got an error message "Unable to connect"

Comment: and running "service jenkins status" I got "jenkins dead but pid file exists"

Comment: @angelo i have same issue