# Empty file in /var/lib/jenkins diectory on centOS

Tags: linux, jenkins, centos7

I am using Jenkins on centOS/Linux server. Now I am facing the same problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253155/empty-var-lib-jenkins-directory-installing-jenkins-on-centos-5-8).
I have tried uninstalling Jenkins more than 2 times, but still getting the same empty file on the /var/lib/jenkins location.
I think I made some mistakes while uninstalling, I used this command to uninstall.

```
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum remove jenkins  
sudo yum install jenkins
```

Is this correct way for uninstalling Jenkins?
And how to get files into the folder /var/lib/jenkins.?

Can anyone tell me to solve this...

Comment: And also How to uninstall jenkins completely in centOS/linux ?

Comment: sudo yum remove jenkins this will uninstall jenkins from the server

Answer (score 0):

You must start `jenkins` first. The `jenkins` itself populates the `/var/lib/jenkins`.

Just use

```
systemctl start jenkins
```

After that open in browser http://localhost:8080